# MongoDB compund index usage with $or

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

We have a compound index like `{a,b,c}` and the query is like

```
{$or:[{a: <value 1>, b: <value 2>}, {a: <value 2>, b: <value 1>}],  c: {$gte: <value c1>, $lte: <value c2>}}
```

Then the index is used only partially i.e

```
indexBounds" : {
                            "a" : [
                                    [
                                            <value 1>,
                                            <value 1>
                                    ]
                            ],
                            "b" : [
                                    [
                                            <value 2>,
                                            <value 2>
                                    ]
                            ],
                            "c" : [
                                    [
                                            {
                                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                                            },
                                            {
                                                    "$minElement" : 1
                                            }
                                    ]
```

and another similar cursor with other combo of values. The resultant data will be filtered on 'c'. Thus we have more nscannned and nscannedobjects than the final result.
 If we have the query as below

```
{$or:[{a: <value 1>, b: <value 2>, c: {$gte: <value c1>, $lte: <value c2>}}, {a: <value 2>, b: <value 1>, c: {$gte: <value c1>, $lte: <value c2>}}]}
```

then the index is completely used and we have nscanned=n
The question - Is this the normal behavior with $or which tries to use index on whatever inside the expression rather than combining the whole query or are we missing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behavior. The query planner is using the index on `{ "a" : 1, "b" : 1, "c" : 1 }` to fulfill the `$or` clause of the query in both cases, since the planner has decided that's the best (only?) way to fulfill the query with an index. Since conjunction distributes over disjunction, `(X OR Y) AND Z` (the structure of your first query) is equivalent to `(X AND Z) OR (Y AND Z)` (the structure of your second query), but the index can be better used for the latter query. The query planner doesn't rearrange the logic of the queries and sometimes there is a better way to write the query so that the query planner can maximize the use of indexes.